# SVG Text centering in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, svg, text, center

I would like to insert a text (maybe multi-line) into a `rect`, **vertically and horizontally centered**. The SVG is created on **server side** in NodeJS, and the result will be displayed in a browser.

SVG does not really support centering text. On the other hand, I have no idea how to calculate width/height of a text on server side to position it properly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know the width/height of the svg viewBox in advance ?

Comment: Yes, actually I create static SVG-s. I know all sizes (viewport, rectangle), but width/height of text. Text is also static. So, there should be a way to calculate.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the width/height, you can position your text element with x,y and set the alignment to middle...

https://jsfiddle.net/ian_b/z9t291nL/1/

```
<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
  <text text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" x="200" y="200">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</text>
  <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="5"/> 
</svg>
```

Its more tricky for multiple lines, and you would need to adjust taking into account font sizes etc.

Comment: Thanks. I read the spec of SVG, but not carefully (I thought I will also need to calculate sizes according to font). But I also need multiple lines. Is there an easy way to read font height from open type fonts in node js? Other calculations are clear to me.

Comment: I mean, I know, that font size is the height of font, but the line height depends on font metrics (in most cases it is roughly 20% larger than font size)